# What is the best way to separate date and time from a nsstring

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `NSStirng` which contains `2013-01-08 07:52:00 +0000`. I would like to separate the date and time in different `NSStrings`.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689179/get-time-and-date-by-nsdate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the format from the server consistent?

Do you need to use the dates and times for anything like sorting etc... or for doing time additions or are you just displaying them?

If you're just displaying them and the format of the string won't change then you can do this...

```
//assumption 1: the format is <date>space<time>space<timezone>
//assumption 2: the only purpose is to display the values sent from the server.

NSString *dateString = @"2013-01-08 07:52:00 +0000";
NSArray *components = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *date = components[0];
NSString *time = components[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, mine is only correct though if the format from the server is suitable to display. With your's you can change the display format of the month, time, etc... :-)

Comment: ya..but for someone who don't need any alternation, this suits well

Comment: see..he accepted! means, he dont want any flexibility!! good answer

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do is to convert your date string into an `NSDate`:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString: @"2013-01-08 07:52:00 +0000"];
```

Then you can use the formatter againt to reverse the process and return a date and time. You can adjust the format of each as required.

```
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];  // Get the time only
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNone];
NSString * timeString = [formatter stringFromDate: date];

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNone];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];  // Get the date only
NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate: date];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below,

```
    NSString *maindateString = @"2013-01-08 07:52:00 +0000";
    NSDateFormatter *myFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [myFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *mainDateDate = [myFormat dateFromString:maindateString];
    [myFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
    NSString *stringDate = [myFormat stringFromDate:mainDateDate];
```

Check the `NSString` **stringDate** and there is what you need :-)

EDIT: To get the time string, add the following code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *myFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [myFormat2 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *stringTime = [myFormat2 stringFromDate:mainDateDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",stringTime);
```

Regards

Comment: 2 things: The month format is incorrect in your answer, and you why are you subtracting 5.5 hours to the date to get GMT?

Comment: @AshleyMills hi, if i did't subtract taht time interval, the time gets advanced by 5.30, which is our time zone in India,compared to GMT

Answer (score 0):

please create a date from that String:

[NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

and then use these (or convert them back to string). That's save.

anyway, you should have had a NSDate before that NSString - did you? why not keeping that one?

Comment: getting it from server as a string .